# Comparing delimited fields

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have two fields in a file, students and teachers. They're delimited by a semicolon and I want to find which single students have two different teachers.

```
jdoe;ateacher
jdoe;bteacher
jsmith;cteacher
bbrown;dteacher
dholden;eteacher
```

Would pipe to:

```
jdoe;ateacher
jdoe;bteacher
```

How can I do this with shell?

**NOTE:** This is homework. I'm not looking for the exact answer, just not sure where to begin. I've parsed and piped this out of a file into the fields I need, now I just need to the find the dupes, but I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: Is the file always sorted like you're showing it?

Comment: Also can there be entries like `jdoe;ateacher` followed by another `jdoe;ateacher`?

Comment: Nope - I've already piped unique's away and it's properly sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the file format you're showing is rigid such that a student only shows up twice if they have 2 different teachers and that the entries for a given student are always right next to each other you could use this command to find all the duplicates. Duplicates in this file denote that a student has multiple teachers, so we could key off this fact.

#### Example

```
$ awk -F';' '{ print $1 }' file | uniq -d
jdoe
```

This parses the file `file` and splits it using `awk`'s field separator switch `-F';'`. We then instruct `awk` to only print the 1st field, i.e. the student's names. We then pipe that output to `uniq` and tell it to only print the duplicate lines.

We could then use this information in a for loop, and only print the lines which have a student in the list that's returned by the command above. Here's a rough structure of what the loop could look like:

```
$ for i in $(..cmd from above..); do 
    ... print lines that contain "$i" ...
done
```

Here we're taking the output from the the initial `awk` command and we're looping through it with a for loop in the Bash shell. This is typically the approach that most people will take when starting out.

#### Example

```
$ for i in $(awk -F';' '{ print $1 }' file | uniq -d); do \
    grep "^$i;" file; done
jdoe;ateacher
jdoe;bteacher
```

This approach, though it works, has some problems. If the names of the files contain spaces, this approach will fail. You can switch to a more sophisticated method like this using a while loop instead.

```
$ while read; do grep "^$i;" file; done \
    < <(awk -F';' '{ print $1 }' file | uniq -d)
jdoe;ateacher
jdoe;bteacher
```

Here we're taking the output from our command and passing it into the while loop like so:

```
$ while read; do .... ; done < <(...our command...)
```

This has the benefit of creating a temporary file with this notation, and passing all the results as lines into the while loop. So the `read` command is now only having to parse the results being split by a newline, rather than a space in the for loop implementation.

```
< <(...command...)
```

#### Example

Here's what happens with the for loop and spaces:

```
$ for i in jdoe john smith jjill;do echo "$i"; done
jdoe
john
smith
jjill
```